# Spring-boot 2 rabbitmq MessageConverter not working as excepted

Tags: spring-rabbit

I am using the springboot and rabitmq. I have kind of similar scenario here.

1. I would like to map my message to custom java object
2. I also want pass  delivery tag which is message proprieties
3. I wann to pass Channel as well beacuse I need to manual ack messages 
   My code is like this

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class EPPQ2SubscriberTest {

    @Autowired
    private RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry registry;
    public final String sampleMessage = "{" + "\"header\": {" + "\"RETRY_COUNT\":0," + "\"PUBLISH_EVENT_TYPE\":\"AUTH\""
            + "}," + "\"payLoad\":{" + "\"MTI\": \"120\"," + "\"MTI_REQUEST\": \"120\","
            + "\"PAN\": \"6011000000000000\"" + "}" + "}";

    @Test
    public void message_converter_test() throws Exception {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = (SimpleMessageListenerContainer) this.registry
                .getListenerContainer("messageListener");
        ChannelAwareMessageListener listener = (ChannelAwareMessageListener) container.getMessageListener();
        Message message = MessageBuilder.withBody(sampleMessage.getBytes())
                .andProperties(MessagePropertiesBuilder.newInstance().setContentType("application/json").build())
                .build();
        listener.onMessage(message, mock(Channel.class));
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableRabbit
    public static class config {
        @Bean
        public ConnectionFactory mockConnectionFactory() {
            return mock(ConnectionFactory.class);
        }

        @Bean
        public MessageConverter messageConverter() {
            Jackson2JsonMessageConverter messageConverter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
            /*
             * DefaultClassMapper classMapper = new DefaultClassMapper();
             * classMapper.setDefaultType(com.discover.dftp.scrubber.domain.Message.class);
             * messageConverter.setClassMapper(classMapper);
             */
            return messageConverter;
        }

        @Bean
        public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory() {
            SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
            factory.setConnectionFactory(mockConnectionFactory());
            factory.setMessageConverter(messageConverter());
            factory.setAutoStartup(false);
            return factory;
        }

        @Bean
        public EPPQ2Subscriber messageListener() {
            return new EPPQ2Subscriber();
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class EPPQ2Subscriber {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EPPQ2Subscriber.class);

    // @RabbitListener(queues = "#{queue.getName()}") @TODO I wann to use this in
    // later point in time.. !
    @RabbitListener(id = "messageListener", queues = "TestQueue")
    public void receiveMessage(Message message, Channel channel/* ,@Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) long tag */) {
        LOGGER.info("Method receiveMessage invoked");
        message.getMessageProperties().getDeliveryTag();
        LOGGER.info("Result:" + message.getClass() + ":" + message.toString());
    }
}
```

```
public class Message implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Map<String, Object> header;
    private Map<String, Object> payLoad;

    public Map<String, Object> getHeader() {
        return header;
    }

    public void setHeader(Map<String, Object> header) {
        this.header = header;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getPayLoad() {
        return payLoad;
    }

    public void setPayLoad(Map<String, Object> payLoad) {
        this.payLoad = payLoad;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Header [header=" + this.header + ", payLoad=" + this.payLoad + "]";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@RabbitListener(id = "messageListener", queues = "TestQueue")
public void receiveMessage(Message message, Channel channel/* ,@Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) long tag */) {
    LOGGER.info("Method receiveMessage invoked");
    message.getMessageProperties().getDeliveryTag();
    LOGGER.info("Result:" + message.getClass() + ":" + message.toString());
}
```

I looks like that method receives the raw (unconverted) Spring AMQP Message (you are importing the wrong `Message` class in `EPPQ2Subscriber`).

Comment: I want get custom java class I called the class name "Message" and I want to pass channel and message properties to receiveMessage.
since I set the factory.setMessageConverter(messageConverter()); this should be mapped to my Custom object.

Could you please give me example of integration for RabiitListenerConfigurer and RabbitListenerEndpointRegistrar How do i invoke a annotated rabbit Listener and call reciveMessage

Comment: I understand that, but `message.getMessageProperties().getDeliveryTag();` indicates to me you are importing **our** `Message` into that class instead of  yours.  Your `Message` doesn't have `getMessageProperties()`. Change the `import` to point to your `Message` and uncomment the delivery tag parameter and all will be well.